# Swift Firebase Delete Post

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I need help deleting a post from firebase. I have the post id key and everything and have been trying all the methods and nothing works. I want to delete the the 3rd child in "posts". I have been trying all types of code. The code below doesn't even throw an error. Not sure what to do. I am getting the values by using a indexpath.row tag.

```
let postID = self.posts[sender.tag].postID    
Database.database().reference().child("posts").child(uid!).child(postID).removeValue { error, _  in
                if error != nil {
                    print("error \(error)")
                }
            }
```

[image]

[image]

**Testing**

I tried this, and this deletes everything under that user...

```
 Database.database().reference().child("posts").child(uid!).queryOrdered(byChild: "postID").queryEqual(toValue: postID).observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
                if snapshot.exists() {
                    snapshot.ref.removeValue()

                    print(snapshot)

                } else {
                    print("snapshot doesn't exist")
                }
            })
```

Comment: code is perfect to delete a post , do one thing open your database parllely when you are removing a child value I think value is getting removed but at same time due to some reference a new post is being added I faced this issue , check all you rDB references

Comment: Did you checked the uId and the postId ?

Comment: Everything is linked up fine. I've don't print outs of all the values. And the database doesn't even change, it doesn't turn red and then green or anything. I know its not deleting from the database and creating new values.

Answer (score 0):

check the value of the reference you want to delete by

```
Database.database().reference().child("posts").child(uid!).child(postID).observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
  print(snapshot.value)
})
```

you can also put them together to check if it's happening locally or not

```
Database.database().reference().child("posts").child(uid!).child(postID).removeValue()
Database.database().reference().child("posts").child(uid!).child(postID).observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
      print(snapshot.value)
    })
```

if it's correct you may don't have access to delete node from the database, check database rules tab in the firebase console

as a last resort you may check your connection because if there is slow connection firebase will cache the updates you make until there is a good connection to sync to the cloud

Comment: With your code the print out I get is "Optional(<null>)". I'll post my security permissions....

Comment: The thing is that I can delete my picture from storage though

Comment: I don't understand why its returning null when the value is still there in the database

Comment: I think my uid is what is coming up as the 'Optional(<null>)' because I printed the uid and postid and the uid prints as "Optional("BZfsFIzmc4MVSOPc5YmKCp2tD552")"

Answer (score 0):

This works.

```
Database.database().reference().child("posts").child(uid!).queryOrdered(byChild: "postID").queryEqual(toValue: postID).observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in
                if snapshot.exists() {

                    snapshot.ref.removeValue()


                    print(snapshot)

                } else {
                    print("snapshot doesn't exist")
                }
            })
```